# Read json from php server

Tags: javascript, json

I want to read json from php server using javascript (not jquery) like

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

            json = xmlhttp.responseText;
            JSON.parse(json, function (key, val) { 
                alert(key + '-'+ val);
            });

        }
}
```

in php file i do

```
$data = array();
$data['id'] = '1';
$data['name'] = '2';

print json_encode($data);
```

But output is

```
id-1
name-2
-[object Object] // why??
```

How to fix that thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using normal javascript, You want to loop through the properties of an object, which u can do it in javascript with `for in` statement.

```
<script>
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

    var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    for(key in data)
{
    alert(key + ' - '+ data[key]); //outputs key and value
}   

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","sample.php",true);    //Say my php file name is sample.php
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

Comment: that's working. Can u explain why my code above don't work? thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the [MDN documentation about `JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

> The reviver is ultimately called with the empty string and the topmost value to permit transformation of the topmost value.

Parsing `{"id":"1","name":"2"}` will generate a JavaScript object. Hence, in the last call of the reviver function, `key` is an empty string and `val` is the generated object.
The default string representation of any object is `[object Object]`, so the output you get is not surprising.

Here is a simpler example:

```
//                              object   vv
alert('Object string representation: ' + {});
```

You usually only use a reviver function if you want to transform the parsed data immediately. You can just do:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

and then iterate over the object or access its properties directly. Have a look at [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) for more information.